# Within Powerquery make multiple API calls updating a Parameter with the max value from a list of records

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

There is seemingly a reasonable amount of documentation on how to use offset or pagination with a rest api call and list generate in PowerQuery.  What I am looking for is similar but using JSON results from a graphQL query.  My struggle is the ability to pull the Max value from the resulting list of records within the JSON response of the graphQL query.  I have tried a few variations.

Any guidance from an PowerQuery expert is much appreciated!

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Converted to Table", "test1", each List.Transform([Value], each [tax_assessor_id])   {0})

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkt4a.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHeRo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97otL.png)
```

Above images you see there is a list of Records that contain 8 fields, I need to be able to grab the Max tax_assessor_id so I can then input it as an updated Parameter within the Function calling the API.

I would also need to put this into List Generate so it iterates through updating the parameter with the max result from the previous API call.  The API is limited to 100 results at a time.

I have been able to make multiple API calls using List Generate as such:

p_taxid is the parameter in the API get.

```
= List.Generate(
 () => [p_taxid = 200000, tadata = fnGetTA(100000)],

 each [p_taxid] <=400000,
 each [p_taxid = [p_taxid] +100000 ,tadata = fnGetTA([p_taxid])]
)
```

but this is an arbitrary value I am simply adding to.

I would want this line:

```
each [p_taxid = [p_taxid] +100000 ,tadata = fnGetTA([p_taxid])]`
```

to be something like

```
 each [p_taxid = *PerviousRow(max('taxdata'[tax_assessor)id]))* ,tadata = fnGetTA([p_taxid])]
```

I believe this can be accomplished via List.Max, but I am not sure how to do that with List of Records that has 2 fields, 1 record is another record that is a list...  that is likely a toung twister...

Thank you for following up, admittedly I am a sql guy... and not Mquery, so I have the concept working, and I understand List.Max, I just don't understand where to execute in the process.

Updated 4/6/2023 10AM

This Code works except I am simply inputting arbitrary additive parameters into the function to make the API call.  what I need to do is replace [p_taxid] +10000 with the max tax_assessor_value in each API call in the list generate the section of the following code
each [p_taxid = [p_taxid] +100000 ,tadata = fnGetTA([p_taxid])]

Here is the entire code set that works, but since my API calls don't have a fixed offset value or page I need to do it based on a parametrized filter while i am sorting the results in the graphQL query.

Here is the entire code set, I am not sure where to place the List.Max function or correct  syntax in order to replace above piece of code.  Apologies I know my ignorance in Mquery makes this difficult...

```
let
    Source = List.Generate(
 () => [p_taxid = 200000, tadata = fnGetTA(100000)],
 
 each [p_taxid] <=400000,
 each [p_taxid = [p_taxid] +100000 ,tadata = fnGetTA([p_taxid])]
),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"p_taxid", "tadata"}, {"p_taxid", "tadata"}),
    #"Expanded tadata" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "tadata", {"tax_assessor"}, {"tax_assessor"}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Expanded tadata", {"p_taxid"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Unpivoted Columns", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"tax_assessor_id", "address", "city", "state", "zip", "latitude", "longitude", "year_built"}, {"tax_assessor_id", "address", "city", "state", "zip", "latitude", "longitude", "year_built"})
in
    #"Expanded Value1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Second row below grabs the max tax assessor ID from a similar structure

```
let Source= #table({"Name", "Value"},{{"tax_assessor",{[tax_assessor_id = 3123, address = 2 ],[tax_assessor_id = 2132, address = 3 ],[tax_assessor_id = 3223, address = 4 ]}}}),
MaxAssessor= List.Max(Table.FromList(Source[Value]{0},Record.FieldValues)[Column1])
in  MaxAssessor
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I added some additional Edits to the problem above, do you know where I could insert the List.Max or format to use that as my parameter value?  Apologies for my MQuery Ignorance... and thanks so much for the help, i owe a virtual drink or coffee!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to puzzle through all that. Perhaps someone else will help here